# How can I merge two hashes?

Tags: ruby, hash

I made two hashes `hash1` and `hash2` with following keys and values.

**Input:**

```
hash1 = {1=>"One", 2=>"Two", 3=>"Three"}
hash2 = {4=>"First", 5=>"Second", 6=>"Third"}
```

**Result:**

And I am expecting `hash3` to give me a result like

```
hash3 #=> {1 => "One", 2 => "Two", 3 => "Three", 4 => "First", 5 => "Second", 6 => "Third"}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can merge these two hashes? Assume that `hash3` should contain all keys and all values.

Comment: How do you expect `hash3` to look like?

Comment: @toro2k I have guessed about that.. :) don't know if OP want it or not.

Comment: How is the result any different from the input?

Comment: I expect hash3 to hold all keys and values... any answer please

Comment: One key can only map to one value.

Comment: @NielsB. Yes, I know... I wanted hash3 to contains all keys and values nothing else.... I don't mean I need one key to hold more than one value

Comment: @Chitransh put the hash3 structure in your post. All we are guessing. help us to stop guess :)

Comment: Please edit your question and update the result section to reflect exactly what output you want.

Comment: Please stop downvoting.... I can't delete this question because it has answers

Comment: Rather you edit your post, with the expected output. Probably down-vote will be cleared out.

Comment: We just want to know what `hash3` should look like. You should add something like `hash3 = {1=>"First", 2=>"Second", 3=>"Third"}` (if that is the `hash3` you want) to your question.

Comment: Well, I am sorry... Because I don't know what kind of edits I should make on this post, Can you edit it ....

Comment: See, you obviously don't want a hash. You want an indexed array.

Comment: Hi all,.... I am really very very sorry that I wrote a poor post but I believe now it contains all information you need to know.... but please remove your downvotes

Comment: Thanks for the edit, no need to be sorry. Please do not be offended because of downvotes. It's not because of you personally, but because the question was unclear.

Comment: Yes... Now I got my mistake, yes my question was totally unclear and It was of poor quality but I've now revised it, Thanks to all for suggesting me edit.

Comment: This is the first time I have seen a user ask a question with the answer to the question already in the title. The irony...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution with minimal coding

```
hash3 = hash1.merge(hash2)
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems you are looking for [Hash#merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge)

```
hash1 = {1=>"One", 2=>"Two", 3=>"Three"}
hash2 = {4=>"First", 5=>"Second", 6=>"Third"}
hash3 = hash1.merge hash2
#=> {1 => "One", 2 => "Two", 3 => "Three", 4 => "First", 5 => "Second", 6 => "Third"}
```

Considering the fact that you access your hash through an increasing sequence of integers, you should think about using an Array instead of a Hash.

```
result = hash1.values + hash2.values
# => ["One", "Two", "Three", "First", "Second", "Third"]
```

This way you can still access your values similarly (e.g. `result[2] #=> "Three"`), but you have a more concise data structure.

Answer (score 3):

If you want 1 to return both "first" and "one", you'll need to store them in an array which will then be the value of which 1 maps to.

```
results = {}

hash1.each do |key, value|
  if results[key].nil?
    results[key] = [value]
  else
    results[key] << value

hash2.each do |key, value|
  if results[key].nil?
    results[key] = [value]
  else
    results[key] << value

results[1]
=> ["one", "first"]
```

#### Update

You obviously don't want a hash. You want an array with the values only.

```
results = hash1.values + hash2.values
=> ["one", "two", "three", "first", "second", "third"]
```

You can access this array just like a hash. Keep in mind that arrays are zero-indexed, so:

```
results[0]
=> "one"
results[2]
=> "three"
results[5]
=> "third"
```

#### Update 2

And now you want a hash after all, because you have unique keys. So:

```
hash3 = hash1.merge(hash2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're learning a new language and are still learning how things work. I'd suggest that with whatever you're working with you take a look at the developer docs.

http://ruby-doc.org/

From there you can search for whatever you're looking for and find other interesting things you can do with the Objects ruby provides for you.

To answer your question specifically you'll need `merge` method for hashes.

`{1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three'}.merge(4: 'Four', 5: 'Five', 6: 'Six)`

Will yield `{1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 4: 'Four', 5: 'Five', 6: 'Six'}`